# Experiment on nuclei decay

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, half-life

I have a doubt (I have already made a similar question, but slightly different):
If I have a bunch of radioisotopes, and I would measure it decay rate and average lifetime,
I measure for a time (finite) $\Delta t$ and in that time $\Delta N$ particles are gone,
what $\frac{\Delta N}{\Delta t}$ means?
I mean, is $\frac{\Delta N}{\Delta t}$ equal to $-\lambda N$ ?(I think no) so what is its relationship with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decay constant what does it means?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674349/)

Comment: You already have what I would call a duplicate (very similar) question (asked yesterday) to this and *that* was marked as a duplicate of another question (and was answered itself as well).  You're not really making clear why this is not a duplicate.  Different words or rephasing the question does not make it fundamentally different IMO.

Answer (score 1):

A graph of the number of unstable nuclei of a particular type, $N(t)$ against time $t$ with be an exponential curve $N(t)=N_0 e^{-\lambda t}$ with a gradient at any time $t$, $\dfrac{dN}{dt} = - \lambda N(t)$.

If the number of unstable nuclei at time $t_1$ is  $N_1$ the number of unstable nuclei at time $t_2$ is  $N_2$ then $\Delta N = N_2-N_1$ and $\Delta t = t_2-t_1$.

$\dfrac {\Delta N}{\Delta t} = \dfrac {N_2-N_1}{t_2-t_1}$ is the gradient of the straight line which joins the points $(t_1,N_1)$ and $(t_2,N_2)$.

As the time interval $\Delta t$ gets smaller the gradient of the straight line gets closer to the gradient of the tangent at time $t_1$.

For the approximation between $\dfrac{\Delta N}{\Delta t}$ and $-\lambda N$ to be a good one you must make sure that $\Delta t \ll \dfrac {1}{\lambda}\approx t_{1/2}$ where $t_{1/2}$ is the half life.